# SSH on Stretch Not Available Sometimes, mDNS not working either

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch

I just clean installed Stretch and set up SSH and a hostname in raspi-config.

On occasion it takes several minutes after boot before I can SSH over IP. Sometimes it never happens and I have to power cycle the Pi.

Also, even though I have a hostname set `greypi`, ssh to pi@greypi.local has never resolved on Stretch for me. This worked fine in Jesse.

What could be going wrong?

Edit: SSH seems to more reliably work if I wait a few minutes after boot. If I try to connect much earlier it seems to lock me out. I enabled "Wait for LAN" in boot settings in the config and it din't help.

Edit2: I gave up. Sick of not getting mDNS or even SSH half the time. I went back to Jesse and it works a treat, therefore, not my network and not the Pi hardware I expect.

Comment: I cannot give you a solution. I occasionally have problems connecting. This is probably NOT a Pi issue (and not specific to Stretch), but related to the network or the source computer. I have found a `ping greypi.local` often wakes the network. Starting a new terminal session on my computer often connects.

Comment: For the `.local` name to resolve, you need to have Apple's bonjour services available. Since it worked on Jessie, I assume you've done this bit. On a Windows machine, you need to specifically install bonjour. Can you ping the RPi during these intervals when you can't use ```ssh```? Do you get any error messages? This sounds like your RPi can't be reached in general. Provide us the details of your networking setup.

Comment: I'm connecting from a Mac so mDNS should be natively supported (indeed the same Pi reliably worked on Jesse). It used to be that you had to change the hostname in a few places and install mDNS on the Pi. But at some point, simply changing it in raspi-config was enough. Seems not now in Stretch?

Comment: I had my Pi on another network and was able to connect vial mDNS (.local). So now I'm thinking it's to do with my LAN. I know access point isolation can break such things but I don't have that installed. Last place to check will be my Powerline route. Will report back, although the SSH issue is still present making testing difficult.

Comment: Disabling `WPS-PBC` seemed to fix .local/mDNS on my home network (DIR-880L Router). I'm not sure what it is or when it was set. Rather odd.